# valgrind does not understand bzero

Tags: c, gcc, memory-management, valgrind

I am allocating enough memory for two pointers which I treat as arrays:

```
// Allocate memory for both adj and deg
int *adjdeg = malloc(sizeof(int)*n*n);

adj = adjdeg;
deg = adjdeg + n*n - n;
```

I am then using GNU's `bzero` from string.h to initialize the values in the `deg` "array" to 0 (the `adj` "array" doesn't need to be initialized to it since I write to it before I ever read from it). This works fine, and my program runs successfully, but valgrind reports many errors about use of initialized values whenever I read from `deg` (IE. `deg[0]`). Here is my call to `bzero`:

```
// My bzero call
bzero(deg, n);
```

valgrind is happy if I remove my call to bzero and use a loop like:

```
int i; 
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    deg[i] = 0;
```

Is there any way to tell valgrind that bzero is initializing that area in memory correctly? I'm using gcc 4.6.3 and valgrind 3.7.0

Note: I get the same errors in valgrind if I use `memset` instead of `bzero`.

Comment: Interesting, `bzero` must be doing something quite different.

Comment: You're allocated `4*n*n` bytes, but only zeroing the first `n` bytes. Do the warnings go away if you zero the whole thing?

Comment: Then the error must be elsewhere. Try `memset(adjdeg, 0, sizeof(int) * n * n);`.

Comment: Ah, I just realized what is wrong. I should be using `bzero(deg, sizeof(int)*n);` since deg is actually meant to be an int pointer to `n` ints, not `n` bytes.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for helping me figure out what was wrong. I don't need to zero the entire thing, but I was only zeroing `n` bytes in the last `4*n` instead zeroing the whole `4*n`.

Comment: use memset instead. If I see bzero in other peoples code I always think: "wtf - that guy is working with code from the 70th"..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be using:

```
bzero(deg, n * sizeof(int));
```

As it is, you're initializing `n` bytes, not `n` integers.  For maximal portability, you should probably use `memset()` instead of `bzero()`, but you still need the `sizeof(int)` multiplier in the size:

```
memset(deg, '\0', n * sizeof(int));
```

Comment: +1 for `memset`. `bzero` is deprecated in POSIX 2001 and nonexistent in POSIX 2008. `memset` is standard in ISO C, and has been since 1989.